# Executable specification ..? how executable specifications can be used for rapid prototyping?

Tags: functional-programming, sml, rapid-prototyping

After reading these books

> Bertrand Meyer, Introduction to the Theory of Programming Languages &
>
> J.D. Ullman, Elements of ML Programming

I have read some papers also, tried to find on google also but I still don't understand this concept. 'executable language semantic specification in functional languages as a rapid prototyping'

I have some questions .. I don't understand meaning of some lines and I have some questions also.. what does this mean and what is 'executable specification'

(1) executable language semantic specification in SML as a rapid prototype of the
language implementation

(2)how executable specifications can be used for rapid prototyping

(3)Denotational semantics provides the “oracle” of the implementation for
imperative programming languages on available architecture/machines.

Answer (score 2):

I'm really just guessing as I haven't read the books you're talking about, but I suspect it is referring to the practice of encoding the semantics of some language as a set of SML functions.  This provides a quick and easy means of playing with the semantics of a language in an executable setting without having to implement all the messy front- and back-end compiler or interpreter artifacts.  For example:

```
datatype value = Int of int
               | String of string

datatype ast = Seq of ast * ast
             | Print of ast
             | Value of value
             | Assign of string * ast
             | Variable of string

fun value_printer (Int i) = print (Int.toString i)
  | value_printer (String s) = print s

fun execute env (Seq (a, b)) = (execute env a; execute env b)
  | execute env (Print a) = value_printer (execute env a)
  | execute env (Value _) = ()
  | execute env (Assign (s, a)) = ...
    etc, etc.
```

You basically define a datatype with which to represent your abstract syntax tree, and then define a function that performs rewriting on this AST (or which reduces AST sub-trees to some `value` datatype that represents values in your language).

If the `execute` function looks vaguely familiar, it's because it resembles more traditional semantic definitions that you might see in a textbook, just with some funny syntax.

You could imagine that we could experiment for building type-checkers, static analyses, or optimizations in this setting without ever having to move out of our "rapid prototyping" environment (which happens to be SML).  SML is really well-suited to these kinds of tasks, which is (I assume) why the books you've read suggest this approach.